# When does .save() create an object?

Tags: python, database, django

I have the code:

```
name = MakesiteNameForm(datdict)
if name.is_valid:
    name.save()

datsite = Makesite.objects.get(sitename=request.POST['sitename'])
datsite.ref_id.add(RefID.objects.create(url=request.POST['url'],description=request.POST['description']))
datsite.save()
```

So i have this bit of code what I want to use to create and save some manytomany items but when I try using this method is says that `Makesite matching query does not exist`. which i think means it hasn't saved but then later I call `site = Makesite.objects.all()` and I can clearly see the value of what `request.POST['sitename']` is sitting inside the querydict. So is there anyway to query this better? or is there something about the save() i missing?

Edit: that form saves a value sitename values into the Makesite table

Answer (score 1):

The save() call doesn't create objects, it just saves the object to the database, inserting a new row in case it's a new object, or updating it.

First, form.is_valid() is a method, but you're not calling it, so you're always trying to save name. That may or may not be related to your error, but it's wrong anyway, and maybe that's where the query error is coming from, not the get() call below. Fix it and see what happens.

Comment: ahh yeah that didn't solve it. thanks for catching that tho but yeah. still have that error. I think it has something ot do with the request.POST['sitename'] i think that needs to be something else?

Comment: You'll have to show some more code then. Other than that, everything seems right.